# Grunt - Dynamically Set Config Before Running a Task

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, gruntjs

So here is my hypothetical config object for a hypothetical fooTask that does something (not relevant to question) to a bunch of JS files

```
grunt.initConfig({
  fooTask: {
    app1: 'app1/*.js',
    app2: 'app2/*.js',
    app3: 'app3/*.js'
  }
});
```

As you can see, with this approach, I have to run fooTask 3 times with each app specified as a target:

```
grunt fooTask:app1
grunt fooTask:app2
grunt fooTask:app3
```

Needless to say this does not scale as either the number of apps increase or the number of such foo tasks increase as one has to C&P the same code over and over for each app.

So ideally what I would like to define is just one target with the name of the app passed in as a config variable

```
grunt.initConfig({
  fooTask: {
    dist: '<%=appName%>/*.js'
  }
});
```

I would then like to call fooTask 3 times, one for each app, with the right app set as appName

```
var apps = ['app1', 'app2', 'app3'];
apps.forEach(function(app) {
  var currAppName = app;

  // Run fooTask but how do I specify the new currAppName config?
  grunt.task.run('fooTask');
});
```

As from code above, I know I can run my fooTask using `grunt.task.run` but how do I set the appName config for my task?

Note that this question is similar to this other one that also does not have the right answer yet - [Pass Grunt config options from task.run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347253/pass-grunt-config-options-from-task-run)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2:**

So nevermind the garbage below the first edit, leaving as example of what doesn't work. In my case it was really important to be able to set the value within a task at run-time so I settled on the file system. Perhaps it suits your needs.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  someTask: {
    someKey: fs.readFileSync('file.txt', { encoding: 'utf8' })
  }
});
```

of course you can do the readFile outside of the task if you need a bunch of different app names.

---

**EDIT:**
Hmmm. I swear I had this working when I wrote this...but now it is not. Grunt just sees the extra arguments as additional unfound tasks.

---

I was trying to figure this out myself, finally a "duh" just moment happened - why not parse [`process.argv`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html) before `grunt.initConfig`?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  var sourcefile = process.argv[2] || 'default.js'; // <- this

  grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
      main: {
        src: sourcefile, // <- voila :)
        dest: sourcefile.substring(0, sourcefile.length-3) + '.min.js'
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('uglify');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
};
```

and use from command line:

```
grunt mykillerscript.js
```

I didn't even try to use grunt.option for the same reason that all the examples only showed directing which task is run, but I wouldn't be surprised if there is a more "grunt" way to do this.

Comment: just realized this doesn't really answer your question about `grunt.task.run` - it still gets our args into the task params though, one step closer.